# Word 2016 opens all files in Web Layout, how to change to Print Layout?

Tags: microsoft-word, page-layout-view

We just upgraded office 2010 to 2016 in our company and a single user has be having issues with this since day 1.
For some unknown reason, everytime they open a document it defaults to Web Layout. Anyone have some ideas as to why this is?

The only time it doesn't happen is when they open a read only doc where it opens in print layout, the only reason that it does that is because I have a RegKey being pushed out that disables Read Layout on read-only docs. (No this isn't the cause because we made this change after as an attempt to fix it).

Answer (score 0):

Create the following [macro](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/open-an-ms-word-document-in-outline-view-by-default/):

```
Sub AutoOpen()
'
' AutoOpen Macro
'
'
ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView 
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHeading 1
End Sub
```

For other options than print view, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdviewtype.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396